# Does the && operator act as an if condition?

Tags: javascript

Does some thing like this

> condition1 && func1 && condition3 && func2

mean

```
if (condition1 ) {
    if (!!func1 ) {
        if (condition3) {
           func2
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it does... `if(condition1 && func1 && condition3) { statement2 }` is equivalent to what you wrote.

Comment: no need for `!!`.

Comment: Yes it does... Why there is doubt about it :o

Comment: Why did `func2` disappear, and what is `statement2` ?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton so just to confirm we can append bunch of && and it acts as if condition and essentially the last statement in that chain will execute if the previous ones execute as true?

Comment: @WaterfrVilla Correct. If you have an if statement `if(cond1 && cond2)`, if `cond1` is false, `cond2` will not even be checked.

Comment: @Katie.Sun What do you mean? You can call functions in an if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Evaluation [short-circuiting](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operadores_Logicos) is a feature of the logical operators AND and OR. It is meant to speed up code execution, you may be making incorrect use of the operator.

**Take this example:**

```js
condição1 &condição2
```

**It's equivalent to this if statement:**

```js
if (condition1) {
    condition2();
}
```

Your statement evaluates `condition1` part of the code only if `condition2` is true.

Use JSLint to detect anti default in your code.

```
console && console.log();
```

http://www.jslint.com/

Comment: If this is not a correct answer. Please update your question so we can better understand.

Answer (score -1):

No it doesn't "act as an if condition".

It is a logical AND operator.

You might *use* it in an `if` condition...:

```
if ( aThing && anotherThing )
{
    // do something...
}
```

There, you are saying "if aThing is true, AND if anotherThing is true, then do something...".